# why list index has different result?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Below is my code.

```
check = [[0] * 4] * 2
check[0][1] = 1
print(check)
check2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0,0]]
check2[0][1] = 1
print(check2)
```

result:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I expect `check` and `check2` get same result but it is different.

why  `check[0][1]` and `check[1][1]` are changed?? not only `check[0][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`check` is a shallow copy**

`check = [[0] * 4] * 2` - Creates only one list `[0,0,0,0]` and rows 1 and 2 **refer** to this list.

So changing the elements of one row reflects changes in every other row.

To avoid such a scenario you can use a `for-loop` to create the list like this

> `check = [[0 for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(2)]`

**Now, this will be a deep copy and not shallow copy.**

**`check2` is a deep copy.**

`check2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0,0]]` - Creates two separate lists `[0,0,0,0]`. Row 1 and Row 2 refers to different copies of `[0,0,0,0]`

So changing the elements of one row will not reflect any changes in the other row.

Please read this SO answer to fully understand the concepts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37830340

Comment: OMG... I didn't know that. Thank you sir.
Ah. Then, there is no way to deep-copy using * ?

Comment: You can use a ```for-loop```. Updated the answer. Please check.